# How to get cakephp query result in normal format?

Tags: cakephp

I have a query like this  **$this->find('all',$query);**.How get the result array of this query just like in normal php?

Comment: I strongly suggest you learn to handle the results in the format CakePHP serves them - it'll make things easier in the long run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$this->getResultInNormalFormat($this->find('all',$query),array('alias1','alias2','alias2'));    
    function getResultInNormalFormat($query_result,$tables){
        $extracted_array = array();
        $i = TRUE;
        foreach($tables as $table){
            $extracted_arrays[] =Set::extract($query_result,'{n}.'.$table) ;
            }
        foreach($extracted_arrays as $extracted_array){
            if($i){
              $merged_array = (Set::merge($extracted_array));
            }
            else{
              $merged_array = (Set::merge($extracted_array,$merged_array));
            }
            $i = FALSE;
            }
        return $merged_array;
         }
```